# Combining rows into concatenated cell with varying numbers of rows

Tags: excel, concatenation, excel-formula

I have a very large Excel sheet converted from a 6000 page PDF file, there are around half a million rows so anything manual is pretty much out of the question.

I am working on converting this to usable data however I have a problem with some of the rows that have been extracted.

The rows should have extracted like this:

```
Date       Text (Date Time TelNo Duration)                     
-----------------------------------------
01/05/2012 29.04.2012 18:31 07[removed]8 00:00:06 
01/05/2012 29.04.2012 18:32 07[removed]8 00:07:22 
01/05/2012 29.04.2012 19:54 07[removed]8 00:00:28
```

Not sure how but around 10,000 of the lines have ended up like this:

```
Date       Text                     
-----------------------------------------
01/05/2012  29.04.2012 
01/05/2012  29.04.2012 
01/05/2012  29.04.2012 
01/05/2012  18:31 
01/05/2012  18:32 
01/05/2012  19:54 
01/05/2012  07[removed]8 
01/05/2012  07[removed]8 
01/05/2012  07[removed]8  
01/05/2012  00:00:06 
01/05/2012  00:07:22 
01/05/2012  00:00:28
```

I am trying to re-combine the rows into single rows (to then split out again).

I have tried the following but it only works for groups of 3 rows:

```
   A           B                    C
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  01/05/2012   29.04.2012      =B1 & B4 & B7 & B10
2  01/05/2012   29.04.2012 
3  01/05/2012   29.04.2012 
4  01/05/2012   18:31 
5  01/05/2012   18:32 
6  01/05/2012   19:54 
7  01/05/2012   07[removed]8 
8  01/05/2012   07[removed]8 
9  01/05/2012   07[removed]8  
10 01/05/2012   00:00:06 
11 01/05/2012   00:07:22 
12 01/05/2012   00:00:28
```

I have also tried various combinations of:

```
=B1&INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH("??:??",B1:B10,0))&INDEX....
```

Can anyone work out a formula that will combine the values and can be dragged/copied down the entire sheet?

**Edit:**

The formula needs to:

On the first row, find the first `Time` value below the current cell followed by the first `Telno` and first `Duration`.
On the second row, find the second `Time` value below the current cell followed by the second `Telno` and second `Duration`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with only formulas:

Step 1.
Added a `Mistype` column and populated with if formulas (Date/Time/Number etc).

Step 2.
Added another new column `NumMissed` with the formula:

```
=IF(D2="date",IF(AND(D2="date",D1<>"date"),MATCH("Time",D2:D20,0)-1,IF(D2="date",E1,"")),"")
```

This displays the number of missed rows which can be used to select the correct cells.

Step 3.
Added another column to hold the retrieved rows (which can then be split up by my other formulas) with the formula:

```
=IF(D2="date",B2&INDEX(B2:B80,E2)&INDEX(B2:B80,E2*2)&INDEX(B2:B80,E2*3)&IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX(B2:B80,E2*4)),INDEX(B2:B80,E2*4),""),"")
```

This gives me data for 99.9% of the rows, the final few can be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a "IF" before the joining of the data:

```
=IF(MID(B1,3,1)=".",B1 & " " & B4 & " " & B7 & " " & B10,"")
```

You can also break it up into columns:

Column C named Time

```
=IF(MID(B1,3,1)=".",B4,"")
```

Column D named TelNo

```
=IF(MID(B1,3,1)=".",B7,"")
```

Column E named Duration

```
=IF(MID(B1,3,1)=".",B10,"")
```

In either case, filter on any rows where Column C is blank.

Comment: The first method is basically what I tried, it fails because the rows are grouped into blocks of anywhere from 1 to 30, I'll expand the question with more detail.